# How to determine if my PowerShell script is being executed by Windows Terminal?

Tags: powershell, host

I want to do something special when my PowerShell script is being executed by [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) and not the normal PowerShell command line or ISE. How to determine that? I checked some built-in variables like `$Host` and can't find related information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Disclaimer: Windows Terminal is still in development at this time of writing and this information could change for the stable release.

Look for the `$env:WT_SESSION` environment variable - this looks to be set to a GUID in a Windows Terminal session, but not when running `powershell.exe` or running `powershell.exe` through ConEmu, both of which I also tested.